# Public folder must be the root if virtual server on Apache is setup correctly

Tags: laravel, apache, server, virtual

My project name is lsapp (which is inside htdocs)
The problem is when I go to localhost or localhost/lsapp the directory of files is shown on the browser. 
I have setup up the C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra
and modified httpd-vhosts.conf as required, Opened hosts files in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and modified as required.
I have checked several times for any typos etc. Everything in these files are now fine.
And there is another file httpd.conf in which I have removed the # in the second line as follows.

.# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

One thing is I have found two http.conf files, in the following different locations. All these files are similar. Do I have to do
1) C:\xampp\apache\conf 
(The setting is as below)
.# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

2) C:\xampp\apache\conf\original
.# Virtual hosts
.#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Also there is one more http-vhosts.conf file inside C:\xampp\apache\conf\original\extra

IT HAS NO # AND IS AS FOLLOWS:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
ServerName dummy-host.example.com
ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
```

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
```

At this point Im not sure about the changes have to me made to these files.

I have restarted Apache and nothing changed.

No codes in this question

The public folder must be the root and the Directory must not be visible on the browser.
On browser lsapp.test gives OBJECT NOT FOUND! ERROR 404 Also it automatically turns to http://lsapp.test/home

Answer (score 0):

This is how the above mentioned files should be setup:

(C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra) **httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
....
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/lsapp/public/"
    ServerName lsapp.dv
</VirtualHost>
```

(C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) **hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       test.com
127.0.0.1       lsapp.dv
```

(C:\xampp\apache\conf) **httpd.conf**

```
#Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

When you open the upper file, remove the **#** character from the beginning of the line so that it should look like the above one.

Then restart your local server and go to browser and type in **lsapp.dv**.

Comment: My httpd-vhosts.conf  is as below. Is it not ok?
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/lsapp/public"
    ServerName lsapp.test
</VirtualHost>

Comment: That is fine. But in your hosts file you have to add  ("27.0.0.1       lsapp.test") and access via the browser like this: ("lsapp.test")

Comment: Still not working. Also lsapp.test become lsapp/home on address bar automatically. The other links are also not working as expected

Comment: All files configured accordingly. @Ahmed Karimi. I am wondering why its not working.

Comment: try http://lsapp.test. I had the same issue for sometime once or twice.

Comment: I am assuming that you have removed the # sign from the line (" Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf ") as mentioned above, right?

Comment: Im using lsapp.test from the beginning but its not working. Anyway, Thank you for your time helping me.

Comment: Yes I have removed # sign on that as well. I can go to localhost and it shows the directory files on browser (which I do not want) Also I cannot browse through my site using the links on the browser